# Getting External JSON Values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to use Morris JS charts and the example I came across currently has this setup. There is the main HTML file index.html,

```
<div id="morris-bar-example" class="dash-chart"></div> 
<script src="assets/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>           
<script src="assets/pages/dashborad.js"></script>
```

Inside of dashborad.js is the following JavaScript,

```
            var $barData = [
            {y: '2006', a: 54, b: 60},
            {y: '2007', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2008', a: 50, b: 40},
            {y: '2009', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2010', a: 50, b: 40},
            {y: '2011', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90},
            {y: '2013', a: 90, b: 75},
            {y: '2014', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2015', a: 50, b: 40},
            {y: '2016', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2017', a: 100, b: 90},
            {y: '2018', a: 90, b: 75}
        ];
        this.createBarChart('morris-bar-example', $barData, 'y', ['a', 'b'], ['Series A', 'Series B'], ['#2f8ee0','#4bbbce']);
```

I'm trying to figure out how can I import these values from an external JSON file, I'm hoping to use PHP to dynamically create the json but I don't know the JS to import the value from this PHP file. Can anyone provide an example of how this would look? Can I just pass a PHP variable directly to dashborad.js and skip the external JSON?

Something like,

```
var $barData = [{y: '2006', a: "<?php echo $val; ?>", b: 60}];}
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass data from PHP to Javascript since the server renders and sends to the client.  Did you try it?

Comment: Tried that exact example but not sure how to echo the PHP variable into the middle of that JSON block inside the JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have a JSON file called "test.json", which contains the following data

```
[
    {"y": "2006", "a": 54, "b": 60},
    {"y": "2007", "a": 75, "b": 65},
    {"y": "2008", "a": 50, "b": 40},
    {"y": "2009", "a": 75, "b": 65},
    {"y": "2010", "a": 50, "b": 40},
    {"y": "2011", "a": 75, "b": 65},
    {"y": "2012", "a": 100, "b": 90},
    {"y": "2013", "a": 90, "b": 75},
    {"y": "2014", "a": 75, "b": 65},
    {"y": "2015", "a": 50, "b": 40},
    {"y": "2016", "a": 75, "b": 65},
    {"y": "2017", "a": 100, "b": 90},
    {"y": "2018", "a": 90, "b": 75}     
]
```

---

**1. How can I import these values from an external JSON file**

Using PHP you can easily do it as follows

```
// Read JSON file
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");

// Decode JSON file i.e. convert it from JSON format into array
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as $arr) {
    echo "y" . ' => ' . $arr["y"] . '<br>';
    echo "a" . ' => ' . $arr["a"] . '<br>';
    echo "b" . ' => ' . $arr["b"] . '<br>';
}

?>
```

---

**2. Use PHP to dynamically create the JSON**

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2"
    ],
    "test2",
    "test3" 
];
// Use json_encode to convert array into a JSON string 
$data = json_encode($data);

// Save that JSON string to a file
// This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.
// If file does not exist, the file is created. 
// Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, 
// unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.
file_put_contents ( "write.json" , $data);

?>
```

---

**3. How to use JS to import the value from this PHP file**

You can use AJAX to get data from PHP file. You can see [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp) to learn more about how to use AJAX

---

**4. Does anyone know of any good tools to convert those JS formatted value and key pairs to the correct JSON format**

You don't need any tools, you can do it using the functions provided by PHP or JS

**In PHP**

1. json_encode(). See docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
2. json_decode(). See docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**In JS**

1. Parse the data with [**JSON.parse()**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.
2. Convert a JavaScript object into a string with [**JSON.stringify()**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to rename dashborad.js to dashborad.php and call it into the index.html file using the same script tag like this,

```
<script src="assets/pages/dashborad.php"></script>
```

Then inside dashborad.php just define the variable and echo it right into the JSON block like this,

```
var $barData = [{y: '2006', a: "<?php echo $val; ?>", b: 60}];}
```

Solution is not optimal as now the server needs to load PHP module everytime this JS file is called but if someone has a better method of doing this without it being super complicated I'd love to learn.

Comment: If you want to keep your .js files as .js and not run them through php. You can always dynamically drop a `<script>var globalVar = <?php echo json_encode($array);?>;</script>` in your actual php core html output. Then your .js files can use that global variable you have dynamically built. I do this all the time, because our .js files are actually minified static cached files.

Answer (score 0):

Better you should use JSON.You can create the $barData at server side and can encode it with json_encode() method like:

```
<?php
$barData= array(..someArray);
$myJSON = json_encode($barData);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

And from your client you can refer this as:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    this.createBarChart('morris-bar-example', myObj[2], 'y', ['a', 'b'], ['Series A', 'Series B'], ['#2f8ee0','#4bbbce']);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "dashboard.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Hope it will solve your problem!